# correction of just a part of a piece of code " Filter " of quicksort in Haskell

Tags: haskell, filtering, list-comprehension

```
Filter :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
 Filter [X:XS] = [[c|c<X, c<-XS ] ++ [X] ++ [c| c >X , c<-XS ]]
 quickSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
 quickSort [] = []
 quickSort [x:xs] = quickSort mini ++ [x] + quickSort maxi
       where
           mini = filter xs
           maxi = filter xs
```

---

Is the function "Filter" with list comprehension correct? I know there is a built-in function "Filter" in Haskell-Libraries. But I tried to write the code by myself...

Comment: If you're trying to re-implement the built-in `filter`, then you should notice that your type signature is wrong - the "real" `filter` also takes a function argument of type `a -> Bool`. Also function names (other than constructors) have to start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: No, there's no built-in function called `Filter`, nor any other function starting with an uppercase character since that's syntactically invalid. **Only** constructors and types can start with an uppercase character, neither function names nor variables can.

Comment: Aside from capitalization issues, `[x:xs]` only matches a list that contains exactly one  non-empty list. Also, the function associated with quicksort is commonly called `partition`, which more accurately reflects what it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're pattern matching on the `:` constructor, use `(x:xs)`. `[x:xs]` is something different.

Always lowercase the first letter of identifiers.  This is a syntax rule in Haskell, not just a convention.

`filter` takes a function of type `(a -> Bool)` as a parameter. It doesn't require an `Ord a` instance.

In a list comprehension, the generator term `x <- xs` must go to the left of any terms that use `x` (i.e. `p x`).

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter p xs = [x | x <- xs, p x]

quickSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
quickSort [] = []
quickSort (x:xs) = quickSort mini ++ [x] ++ quickSort maxi
    where
        mini = filter (< x) xs
        maxi = filter (>= x) xs
```

Comment: Thanks for your helps!! Could you tell me what is the differences between (x:xs) and [x:xs]. And in this case we prefer the (x:xs)?

Comment: Could I write other Characters for example "x" instead of "xs" or that is a convention oder rule in the code " filter p xs = [x | x <- xs, p x]". I can see the logic of the code. xs stands for the tail of the list we need.

Comment: @FengxiangHu you can try it out in GHCi. For instance, `[1:[2,3,4]]` gives `[[1,2,3,4]]`, i.e. a list containing a single list (which has four elements). Whereas `(1:[2,3,4])` is just `1:[2,3,4]` in parentheses, i.e. it's simply the four-integer list `[1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: `[x:xs]` matches any list which contains a single element, and that element matches `x:xs`. In other words, it matches a non-empty list of lists, with `x` being the first such list and `xs` being the remaining list of lists. 99% of the time, that isn't what you want.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid am I confused here, or your comment above isn't quite right? :)

Comment: (1:[2,3,4])  i.e  ([1,2,3,4]). I think that means a single element in Tupel